# Python: Function names as if conditions

Tags: python, function

I've recently come across a test question that uses a function name as part of the if condition, and I have no idea what it is checking against.
For instance,

```
def function():
      return 6
if function:
      print('Output1')
else:
      print('Output2')
```

This always seems to give the 'Output1' rather than the 'Output2', I don't know how to make the if statement condition false.

Comment: You can't make it false. A function is truth-y. Most objects, except things like zero numbers and empty sequences, are truth-y: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing.

Comment: Perhaps the point that isn't clear here is that Python treats functions as first-class objects. Meaning you can assign names to functions dynamically, pass them around as arguments, and so forth. And test them for truthyness. This is distinct from checking the _value_ of a function. There are various articles explaining this in depth out there, eg https://dbader.org/blog/python-first-class-functions for a decent one if you don't mind the ad/newsletter solicitation before getting to the real content.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about `def` this way, as `object creation` + `assignment`, makes it easier to understand a variety of different situations.

`def` creates a new function object in python, So when you write:

```
>>> def foo():
>>>     return 5
```

`def` creates an object with name `foo` and assigns the function to it.

Try this example:

```
>>> f = 10
>>> def f():
...     return 5
...
>>> f
```

In your test, `function` always has a value and it isn't `None`, So you can't make the `if function:` false

[Reference](https://lerner.co.il/2018/03/20/four-ways-to-assign-variables-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

The comments are good. To put it in answer form:

`function` points to the content of the function: it takes no arguments, and returns the value 6.

`if function` tests the truthy-ness of the function itself, not what it returns. This will always evaluate as `True`.

If you want it to return true or false based on the return value, you want to invoke the function, with the parentheses to show it is a function call: `function()`. Note that b/c this function returns `6` this also will always evaluate to True, as non-zero numbers evaluate as True. You would need your function to do return different values if you want different outcomes, such as:

```
import random
def function():
    return random.choice([0,6])

if function():
    print('Output1')
else:
    print('Output2')
```

This function will now return either `0` or `6`, and so should evaluate to True or False 50% of the time each.